# How to integrate bitly api to shorten my link in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I created an app which get the url of my youtube videos in the text field using GData Client Library.  Now i want to shorten that url using bitly api..  But i don't have an idea about that.

if anybody done it before me, please tell me how you did it.

Thanks,

Chakradhar.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick and easy way of doing it.
You will need to register with bit.ly and obtain a login name and API key.

```
NSString *username = @"user";
NSString *apiKey = @"R_11111111111111";
NSString *url = @"yoururl.com";

NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", username, apiKey, url]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: note this is sync and might cause the app to hang for a second if slow network

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iOS wrapper for bit.ly api https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bitly

Answer (score 1):

This has worked well for me, and since it is a synchroeous request there is a slight delay to fetch the link so you may want to display a Progress HUD:

```
  NSString *accessToken = YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  NSString *url = YOUR_URL;

  NSString *bitlyRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=%@&longUrl=%@",accessToken, url];
  NSString *bitlyResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bitlyRequest] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

  NSData *data = [bitlyResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSDictionary *bitlyDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

  NSString *bitlyUrl = bitlyDictionary[@"data"][@"url"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with theri [API documentation](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation).